# Routing in Play framework 2.0 doesn't work for standalone application under Nginx

Tags: deployment, routes, nginx, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play framework 2.0.
I'm creating a standalone app using "play dist".

Also I'm using Nginx as a frontend.
So, I have Nginx config:

```
location /terra {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;

         proxy_redirect          off;
         proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }
```

My routing file looks like:

```
GET /  controllers.Application.index()           
GET /projects     controllers.Application.projects()
```

When I start an application like

```
sh start -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.port=9000
```

or just

```
sh start
```

and go to http://hostnamehere/terra I get:
Action not found For request 'GET /terra'

If I change `GET /  controllers.Application.index()` to `GET /terra  controllers.Application.index()` - it doesn't work too.

Also when I run my app locally and go to "localhost:9000/WRONG_ROUTING_NAME" I get the same error, but I can see "These routes have been tried, in this order: " and the listing of the methods. I can't see the same listing after the app is deployed.

When I use `curl myhost.com:9000` I get: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` – Azee 12 secs ago edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in different Java versions.
The app was compiled using java 7, but the remote server was running the app on java 6.

I compiled and packed the app in java 6 and it solved the problem.

Now I'm using different architecture of web applications but that particular app is still running on 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't in routing.
If you run `play dist` you get a standalone application. But you can run it only on the same local machine. It seems that "dist" also copies some config files somewhere. If you want to run a standalone application on the remote server you have to call `play dist` on that host.
I couldn't find anything about that in Play docs. But I need this information to prepare debian packages...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that to run app created by "dist" it is not enough to copy only created directory. You have to copy whole project directory with created one - unpacked from zip (or some specific files?) and run application from that directory.

Comment: I experimented a little bit.
To run application the structure of derictories must remain. 
Eg., you have a directory projectName/, it contains a project. When you run "play dist" a projectName/dist/artifactName.zip file is created.
You have to unpack this file in the same directory on the remote host:
projectName/artifactName/
Then you can run "sh start" from directory projectName.

Comment: Nope. The problem was that I created application locally on jdk7, and on the remote server there was java 1.6...

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?  You are the only contributor to this question, and a complete answer would be very valuable.  Googling around this for several days leads me to believe I have to install Play on my EC2 server in order to run the dist, but before I do that I would like to see how you got it working.